# Asymptotic complexity of T(n)=T(n-1)+1/n

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion

There is an algorithm which has the time complexity

```
    T(n)=T(n-1)+1/n if n>1
        =1          otherwise
```

I am solving for its asymptotic complexity, and getting order as 'n' but the answer given is 'log n'. Is it correct? If it is log n, then why?

Comment: Please show the way you get to O(n).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: @interjay You should also submit that as an answer

Comment: @jamylak: Done, I didn't have time to do so earlier.

Comment: @interjay thank you for the explanation. However I think question should be edited to indicate what the OP really means as I am not the one to get confused by it.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: OK, I think it should be clearer now.

Comment: @interjay definitely. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be easily seen (or proven formally with induction) that T(n) is the sum of 1/k for the values of k from 1 to n. This is the *n*th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), H<sub>n</sub> = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n.

Asymptotically, the harmonic numbers grow on the order of log(n). This is because the sum is close in value to the integral of 1/x from 1 to n, which is equal to the natural logarithm of n. In fact, H<sub>n</sub> = ln(n) + γ + O(1/n) where γ is a constant. From this, it is easy to show that T(n) = Θ(log(n)).

Answer (score 3):

For more details:

With `H(N) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/N`

the function `x :-> 1/x` is a decreasing function so :

[image]

We sum from `1 to N` the left part and for the right part we sum from `2 to N` and we add `1`, we get:

[image]

Then we calculate the left and right parts : `ln(N+1) <= H(N) <= 1 + ln(N)`

this implies   `H(N)/ln(N) -> 1` hence `H(N)=Θ(log(N))`

(from http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_harmonique#.C3.89quivalent_de_Hn)